# Priorities with actions in bge

Tags: game-engine, actions

I am working on a character for a game that has 3 main actions: Walking, Running, and Idle. S1 and S2 stand for Scenario 1 and Scenario 2, respectively. I have all the priorities set to 0.

[image: My setup for actions]

I want the priorities to be in an order where if Sonic runs or walks, the animations will play, but if neither of those things are happening, he will remain Idle. I have tried multiple combinations of priority orders, but I could not find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

After almost a month of trying, I finally figured out what was wrong. Since you had to move the Up-Axis to walk, and the Up-Axis + Y  to sprint, you need to put the run action on layer 1, since it has the same control.